# Can’t get ssh status?

Tags: ssh, sshd

I was following this to starting an ssh server on my ubuntu pi. I ran `sudo systemctl status ssh`, and I got the response (ellipses where un-useful stuff was):

```
Loaded: loaded (...
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-01-29 ...
Docs man:sshd(8)
man:sshd_config(5)
... status=1/FAILURE
...
```

I don’t know how to handle this or where to look for information.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: You could try something like `journalctl -xeu ssh.service` to get more information